# Setting up GIT and CICD Multiple Shopify Sites

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, shopify

Firstly, I am new to GIT, so I apologize if this is a terrible question.

I have a 4 Shopify stores for a brand (Canada, US, EU and UK). I am trying to configure or at least understand the best method to architect GIT for these 4 sites.

We are using Github.

1. The sites share 99% similar code bases. So what I'm thinking is to have a branch for each site, and have a master branch. Then when code changes are committed in the master branch, pull in changes to each "country" branch and exclude certain files. (Not sure this is possible)
2. When code banner changes are done (when customizing the theme in Shopify) the code is changed. Then if we deploy code changes, these banners, etc need to be manually fixed again. I'd like to use something like dploy.io to grab Shopify code and pull it into the "country" branches once a day. (Also, not sure if this is possible).
3. Lastly, I'd like to be able to click a button to deploy code changes from Git to the Shopify store. I'm guessing that dploy can also do this.

Looking for thoughts or maybe a simple reality check of my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for international brands that have multiple stores that are almost identical, it's best to have a "master" theme sitting in one repo, and that theme is pushed to all stores - that way you're only maintaining one codebase.

For the 1% of differences, you can set up a toggle system in your theme settings. Take GDPR as an example, you would toggle that feature as "on" for your European stores, and could toggle as "off" for AU/US. (Just an example, not debating whether that's the right feature to toggle!)

You can use [Shopify's Theme Kit](https://shopify.dev/tools/theme-kit) to deploy to each store individually from your local environment, or can rig up some CI/CD workflows to do the same with Github Actions or similar.